# Safely clean McAfee logs

Tags: logging, anti-virus

Directory C:\ProgramData\McAfee\MCP\Logs takes up 3.2GB.
From the name of the directory, it appears that the logs are for McAfee Client Proxy (MCP).

The files in that directory have the following names:

- `McpContinuousEtlTraces.etl_<#>` (with `<#>` being a 1 to 5-digit number).
  A few of these files have 153600Kb, as if it were the maximum allowed size.
  Six other files have tens of Mb.
  And more than 1800 files have <= 4Kb.
- `Mcp.log` (0 Kb)
- `ContinuousTraceRun.log` (404kb)

It appears that I could dispense with a large part of it, if not all, but I am not sure.
I am not sure either if simply deleting them is fine, or that should be done via other means which take care of some index accordingly, e.g.

**Is there any safe way of cleaning up that directory?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any safe way of cleaning up that directory?

The logs generated by McAfee Client Proxy are controlled and managed by McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator (McAfee ePO).  You would need to make the appropriate modifications to the ePO server to prevent additional logs from being generated.

As an elevated user, you would be able to delete the logs in question, I would not attempt to delete these logs without getting permission from an authorized user on your network.

Logs generated by MCP are typically generated for a specific reason.  If any user were to, destroy logs generated by any application I specifically enabled, they would find themselves without access to my network, aproxmently 5 minutes after I discovered those logs went missing.

> I am not sure either if simply deleting them is fine, or that should be done via other means which take care of some index accordingly, e.g.

Logs files are safe to delete, they only contain data they were configured to contain, but their existence serves a specific point.  In your specific case, normal users do not typically have enough permissions, to delete files contained within any folder within `C:\ProgramData\` which would include `..\McAfee\MCP\Logs\`

Comment: I take from your answer that logs for any application are safe to delete, with good old <del> (from the point of view of correct operation of the PC). I was wary about this point...
As for the right person/authorization level to do so, of course I agree with you. That applies to a corporate environment, as well as a family, e.g.
As for the usefulness of logs, persistently over time, this wouldn't be the first time that people (admins, e.g.) don't care/don't have the mission about setting up proper cleanup.

Comment: For instance, I found file Autoztemon.txt that grows up to more than 1 Gb, with info that is useless over time.

Comment: You might think the data is useless but your Administrator enabled those logs for a reason

Comment: I never meant log data is useless (I hope I didn't give that impression).
What I mean is that after some time they become *essentially* useless (corner cases are always imaginable).
And an admin certainly confirmed that in many cases there is no mechanism in place to cleanup logs, simply because the default is that there is none, not because they explicitly mean to keep logs indefinitely.

Comment: @sancho.s - Why do you care if you gave that impression?  My answer was for any user on a corporate network thinking about making unauthorized changes or removing logs without specific permission.

Comment: Why? Because that may obfuscate the intention of the question.
PS: It turns out that I can remove those files.